# How to send POST value to website?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I need to submit value from my application via UITextField and I want this value to show on website that i sent request to. I use ASIHTTPRequest to send request to website. i tried something like this:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.project4hire.com/freelance_job_16265.html"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
//
[request setPostValue:priceField  forKey:@"bid"];
[request setPostValue:dayField forKey:@"days2c"];
[request setPostValue:commentField forKey:@"comment"];
[request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"notify"];
[request setPostValue:@"placebid" forKey:@"Place Bid >>"];
[request setPostValue:@"e6fb12104854e6e9" forKey:@"suid"];
[request setPostValue:@"placebid" forKey:@"a"];
[request setPostValue:@"16265" forKey:@"pid"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestBidFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestBidFinished:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

}
- (void)requestBidFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
//notify user
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sending         request to the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}

- (void)requestBidFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSLog(@"Status: %d", request.responseStatusCode);
NSLog(@"string: %@",request.responseString);
}
```

Here are the Bid Form:[BidForm](http://pastebin.com/kViv3bT6)
Here are request and response header:[Header](http://pastebin.com/YCNPqG96)

I got response 200, but the value that i sent not show on the website. Can anyone advice me?

Thanks

Comment: You're probably gonna have to post the code to your form as well.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are posting to a HTML file. Unless you have some special setup to allow The HTML files to be executable, the html file will not process the data you posted to it. Is it that only one value is not showing or are all values not showing. If all values are missing, then what I stated initially is correct and you will need to use something like PHP, CF, Perl or whatever language you want to receive the data you are posting from your app.

Comment: All value are not showing. For your noticed, i think you tell me in case that i create my own website but in my case this website is not mine. Any idea?

Comment: @septi, Most web servers are configured to not allow code execution on .htm and .html files by default. But Of couse you can certainly change that in your web server configuration which is what i was eluding too.

Comment: @Kalvin, well if you dont have control over the site you are posting to, it will make it harder. Can you provide any details about the site you are attempting to post thedata to?

Comment: @Sly Raskal: almost every web server I worked on in the past 15 years had PHP allowed in html-files.

Comment: @SlyRaskal i update the html form and the request and response header. is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but mine was working on simulator but it was not working on device then I read an article that it shows the founders of the ASIHTTPRequest API no longer update their library (I dont know if that article was reliable or not), so I decided to use an updated library which is RestKit. You can download and set it up from this website: restkit.org, if you have any problem for installing you can ask me to help you. here are the simple code for posting on restkit library:

```
- (void)post
{
    [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://www.project4hire.com"];

    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            priceField, @"bid",
                            dayField, @"days2c", nil];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/freelance_job_16265.html" params:params delegate:self];
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSRange range = [[error localizedDescription] rangeOfString:@"-1012"];
    if (range.length > 0){
        //Do whatever here to handle authentication failures
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sending         request to the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    RKLogError(@"Hit error: %@", error);
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response
{
    if ([request isGET]) {
        // Handling GET /foo.xml

        if ([response isOK]) {
            // Success! Let's take a look at the data
            NSLog(@"Retrieved XML: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        }

    } else if ([request isPOST]) {

        // Handling POST /other.json
        if ([response isJSON]) {
            NSLog(@"Got a JSON response back from our POST!");
        }

    } else if ([request isDELETE]) {

        // Handling DELETE /missing_resource.txt
        if ([response isNotFound]) {
            NSLog(@"The resource path '%@' was not found.", [request resourcePath]);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"HTTP status code:     %d", response.statusCode);
    NSLog(@"HTTP status message:  %@", [response localizedStatusCodeString]);
    NSLog(@"Header fields: %@", response.allHeaderFields);
    NSLog(@"Body: %@", response.bodyAsString);
}
```